# Server-wise what do I need to do to serve the same app for different domains?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, apache-2.4

I'm setting up a Rails app behind passenger ad Apache (or Nginx). What I want to do is server the same app in multiple domains.

The app will be a multi-domain app and it'll have some specific logic to manage different domains internally.

My question is related to the server itself. In my local machine (OS X with Apache, Passenger, etc), I can achieve this by creating a vhost configuration file and changing the hosts file.

On a Ubuntu server, would it be required? I imagine the hosts file wouldn't need change as this would be done through a DNS server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the configuration of the vhosts in apache or nginx must be done almost the same way you made it on your development machine to allow the server to accept the clients and direct them to the correct application.

the 'hosts' part has not to be done, as you said, because the resolution of the domain name will be carried on by the DNS system on the internet: you have to register the relevant domain names and associate them with the public address of the ubuntu server but it is not required any configuration on the server itself.

Comment: That's what I though. Thanks for the clarification.